# Rails undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I receive this message when i attempt to create a new record from a nested form. The strange thing is when I just backspace to the previous page(page with the 'create' button) and hit 'create' again, the record is created. So I am not sure why it won't create the record the first time as I don't change the create method in my controller during the first and second button press. Anyone experience this before that can help me understand why this is happening would be great.

Models

```
class Benefit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :employee_benefits
  has_many :benefit_plans, :inverse_of => :benefit   
  belongs_to :benefit_coverage_period
  belongs_to :benefit_type_id, :class_name => "LookupTable", :foreign_key => "benefit_type"

  attr_accessible :account_id, :active, :attachment, :automatic_rollover, :id, :benefit_id, :benefit_type_id 
  attr_accessible :benefit_coverage_id, :benefit_type, :is_pretax, :benefit_coverage_period_id
  attr_accessible :description, :enrollable, :link, :name, :has_plans, :has_custom_amount, :benefit_plans_attributes

  validates_format_of :link, :message => "Please enter a valid URL", :with => /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :benefit_plans, allow_destroy: true
end

class BenefitPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :benefit, :inverse_of => :benefit_plans
  validates_presence_of :benefit
  has_many :employee_benefits
  has_many :benefit_coverages

  attr_accessible :benefit_id, :description, :name, :benefit_coverages_attributes, :link, :attachment

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :benefit_coverages, allow_destroy: true
end

class BenefitCoverage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :benefit_plan  
  has_many :employee_benefits
  belongs_to :name_id, :class_name => "LookupTable", :foreign_key => "name"

  attr_accessible :benefit_plan_id, :name, :paycheck_deduction, :percentage_split, :total_cost

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee_benefits
end
```

Controller

```
def new
  @benefit = Benefit.new
  @benefit_coverage_periods = @account.benefit_coverage_periods
  1.times { @benefit.benefit_plans.build(:name => 'Default Plan') }
  @lookup_tables = LookupTable.where(:active => :true).find_all_by_group(30) || []
  @lookup_tables1 = LookupTable.where(:active => :true).find_all_by_group(31) || []
end

def create
  @benefit = Benefit.new(params[:benefit])
  @lookup_tables = LookupTable.where(:active => :true).find_all_by_group(30) || []
  @lookup_tables1 = LookupTable.where(:active => :true).find_all_by_group(31) || []
  @benefit_coverage_periods = @account.benefit_coverage_periods

  if @benefit.save
    redirect_to benefits_path, :notice => 'Benefit was successfully created.'
  else
    render :action => "new"
end
```

View

```
= form_for @benefit, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }, :validate => true do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :account_id, :value => @account.id
  .control-group
    = f.label :name, :class => "control-label"
    .controls
      = f.text_field :name, :class => "text_field"
  .control-group
    = f.label :benefit_type, "Benefit Type", :class => "control-label"
    .controls
      = f.collection_select :benefit_type, @lookup_tables1, :id, :title, :prompt => true
...
```

Error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass:
15:00:09 web.1   |   actionpack (3.2.14)                   lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:364:in `options_from_collection_for_select'
15:00:09 web.1   |   actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:600:in `to_collection_select_tag'
15:00:09 web.1   |   actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:191:in `collection_select'
15:00:09 web.1   |   actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:646:in `collection_select'
15:00:09 web.1   |   client_side_validations (3.2.6) lib/client_side_validations/action_view/form_builder.rb:77:in `collection
_select_with_client_side_validations'
15:00:09 web.1   |   app/views/benefits/_form.html.haml:10:in `block in _app_views_benefits__form_html_haml___5210787370672092
58_70323180464100'
15:00:09 web.1   |   haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:132:in `block (2 levels) in form_for_with_haml'
15:00:09 web.1   |   haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers.rb:284:in `with_tabs'
15:00:09 web.1   |   haml (4.1.0.beta.1) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:132:in `block in form_for_with_haml'
15:00:09 web.1   |   actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `block in capture'
15:00:09 web.1   |   actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:187:in `with_output_buffer'
...
```

Answer (score 8):

The stack trace tells you everything you need to know to figure this out. Let's learn to fish!

First of all "Undefined method X for Y" means "You tried to call a method `X` on object `Y`, but `Y` doesn't have that method". In this case, you're trying to call `map` on nil, and nil doesn't implement `map`. So we're looking for a place that we call `map`, and then we're going to try to figure out why the object we're calling `map` on could be nil.

> 15:00:09 web.1   |   app/views/benefits/_form.html.haml:10:in `block in _app_views_benefits__form_html_haml___5210787370672092

This tells you to look on line 10 in _form.html.haml. That's where you're going to fix the issue. However, the issue happens in `lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:364` in the `options_from_collection_for_select` method. It's a pretty good guess that that corresponds to this line:

> = f.collection_select :benefit_type, @lookup_tables1, :id, :title, :prompt => true

If you look at the source there, you can see what it's calling. Working backwards from the top of the stack trace:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.14/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L364
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.14/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L600
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.14/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L191
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.14/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L646

We can see that it's calling `map` on the `collection` that is passed in. By following the stack trace back to the `FormBuilder#collection_select` method, we can determine exactly which parameter this is - `@lookup_tables1`, in your case.

Now, `@lookup_tables1` is set in your `new` action, but it's not set in your `create` action, when you `render action: :new`. From this, we can surmise that the first time you try to save your Benefit record, the `save` fails and returns false. Your second branch is run there, which attempts to render the `new` template, but because you didn't set `@lookup_tables1`, the `collection_select` fails as it's attempting to create a select box from a nil collection.

So, you have two tasks:

1. Populate your `@lookup_tables1` from your `create` method before you call `render action: :new`
2. Figure out why your Benefit record is failing to save, and fix that.

As an aside, you should update Rails to the the latest 3.x series (3.2.19 as of right now). 3.2.14 has several vulnerabilities that have been since fixed.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the excellent explanation and education. I've updated my code and now the page renders :action => "new" with no errors. However, it still won't save/create with first submit. Do you know or have heard of why before the record would not get created on first submit but would on second?

Comment: There are lots of reasons why that could be the case. You might try calling `#save!` rather than `save`, since that will throw an exception when the record fails to save. You could alternately look at the contents of `#errors` on the record after a failed save to determine why it isn't behaving.

Comment: Great suggestion on #save! The error is with validation -- Validation failed: Benefit plans benefit coverages benefit plan can't be blank.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm using a nested form. So from my limited understanding, perhaps my model associates are not correct. However, I'm still confused on why a second submit would then create the record with all the proper associated fields. Models added above.

Comment: To be honest, I've not really used nested forms too much (mostly because I always seemed to have tremendous trouble with them). However, I'd suggest using the pry gem -- slap a `binding.pry` there in your create action and you can inspect the state of your models before it's saved, etc, and see if its state matches what you expect.